# group by has element

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by

Im trying to do a query with the following.  I have simplified the query as much as possible for purposes of the question.  It is basically for an email schedular app I am writing.

Two tables.  An email can belong to a particular schedular.  A schedular comprises of several emails.  Each email that has been sent is marked with a specific step number.  step1, step2, step3, step4, step5

```
email_schedular (id, datecreated, recipient)
email(id, email_schedular_id, text, subject, sent, stepNumber)
```

Now what im trying to do is determine in a report if a step has been sent or not.  I have had a go at it but im not sure if im going about it the right way?

```
SELECT
  ed.id,
  ed.datecreated
  ed.recipient
  if(e.stepNumber= 1, 'Y', 'N')  AS step_1_sent,
  if(e.stepNumber= 2, 'Y', 'N')  AS step_2_sent,
  if(e.stepNumber= 3, 'Y', 'N')  AS step_3_sent,
  if(e.stepNumber= 4, 'Y', 'N')  AS step_4_sent
FROM 
  email_echedular ed
JOIN email e ON (e.email_echedular_id = ed.id)
GROUP BY ed.id
```

Comment: I dont know, it doesn't work. Id be interested in knowing whats wrong it it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `N` for not sent, use a `NULL`. Then when you group them, you can take the `MAX()` value for each and eliminate the NULLs down to one row. The end result should be one row per `ed.id` with a `Yes` for sent steps and `NULL` for unsent steps.

```
SELECT
  ed.id,
  ed.datecreated
  ed.recipient
  MAX(if(e.stepNumber= 1, 'Y', NULL)) AS step_1_sent,
  MAX(if(e.stepNumber= 2, 'Y', NULL)) AS step_2_sent,
  MAX(if(e.stepNumber= 3, 'Y', NULL)) AS step_3_sent,
  MAX(if(e.stepNumber= 4, 'Y', NULL)) AS step_4_sent
FROM 
  email_schedular ed
  LEFT JOIN email e ON (e.email_schedular_id = ed.id)
GROUP BY ed.id
```

If you really don't want a `NULL` for the non-sent columns, you can wrap those in `COALESCE()` to replace the `NULL` with `N`:

```
SELECT
  ed.id,
  ed.datecreated
  ed.recipient
  COALESCE(MAX(if(e.stepNumber= 1, 'Y', NULL)), 'N') AS step_1_sent,
  COALESCE(MAX(if(e.stepNumber= 2, 'Y', NULL)), 'N') AS step_2_sent,
  COALESCE(MAX(if(e.stepNumber= 3, 'Y', NULL)), 'N') AS step_3_sent,
  COALESCE(MAX(if(e.stepNumber= 4, 'Y', NULL)), 'N') AS step_4_sent
FROM 
  email_schedular ed
  LEFT JOIN email e ON (e.email_schedular_id = ed.id)
GROUP BY ed.id
```

**Edit** Changed to `LEFT JOIN` and fixed join condition...

Comment: its still flagging it as Y, when is should not be?

Comment: @Robbo_UK I had just made a change to the join condition. Make sure you're testing the latest, and failing that, please post some sample data.

Comment: The Left join did it.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: Why do you need to use max?  What does it do?

Comment: @Robbo_UK If you used `GROUP BY` without the `MAX()` aggregate function, you would get back only the first matched row for any email's `stepNumber`, so effectively you'd only ever get one step back.  The `MAX()` will take the one that has a `Y` value for each step type and push it into a single row, since aggregate functions eliminate NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ed.id,
  ed.datecreated
  ed.recipient
  if(e.stepNumber= 1, 'Y', 'N')  AS step_1_sent,
  if(e.stepNumber= 2, 'Y', 'N')  AS step_2_sent,
  if(e.stepNumber= 3, 'Y', 'N')  AS step_3_sent,
  if(e.stepNumber= 4, 'Y', 'N')  AS step_4_sent
FROM 
  email_echedular ed
JOIN email e ON (e.email_echedular = e.id)
GROUP BY ed.id
```

in this line `JOIN email e ON (e.email_echedular = e.id)` WHO IS `e.email_Echedular`?
change that  to `JOIN email e ON (e.email_Schedular = e.id)`